# Error in use inner join table column in WHERE

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, inner-join, where-clause

I have this code + one error!

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM Takhfif 
 WHERE CategoryID = 2 
 INNER JOIN Category ON Takhfif.CategoryID = Category.CategoryID
```

Error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pure syntax error. Write like this

```
SELECT * FROM Takhfif  
INNER JOIN Category  ON Takhfif.CategoryID = Category.CategoryID
where Takhfif .CategoryID=2
```

The Normal Order of writing Select statements like

1. SELECT
2. FROM (Including Joins & ON AND Conditions)
3. WHERE
4. Group By
5. Having
6. ORDER By

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept the answer if it is fulfilled your requirement.